# Meteor exception in nested templates - Expected template or null, found <blank>

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

Trying to implement a nested template structure -

```
<template name="parent">
  <ul>
    {{#if parenthelper}}
    {{parenthelper}}
      <li>    
        {{> child}}
      </li>
    {{/if}}
  </ul>
</template>

<template name="child">
    {{#if children.length}}
       <ul>
           {{#each children}}
           {{children}}
               <li>
                   {{> child}}
               </li>
           {{/each}}
       </ul>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

And js

```
Template.parent.helpers({
    'parenthelper': function(){
        console.log("description is " + this.description);
        return this.description;
    }
});

Template.child.helpers({
    'children': function(){
        var child_list = [];
        var data = Template.parentData();
        console.log("id " + data._id);
        if (data != null) {
            if (typeof data._id != 'undefined') {
                ItemList.find({parent: data._id}, {description:1, _id:0}).forEach(function(u) { child_list.push(u.description) });
                console.log("childlist " + child_list);
                return child_list;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
});
```

How it works - I click on a item link, which loads page with the item details (mongo) and recursive list of all children under than item.

As an example, I click on an item that has one child item and no other levels. I'm seeing this debug output which is not entirely clear to me -

```
description is undefined
description is parentdesc
description is parentdesc
id undefined
```

Why is the id (Template.parentdata._id) undefined ?

Example data:

```
{ "_id" : "2ENP9grLxHmCLNYfm", "username" : "hWvHzBCjs3TuttLMJ", "description" : "parent item 1", "startdate" : ISODate("2018-08-08T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "IN PROGRESS", "parent" : null }
{ "_id" : "PbZZHDusi5CYbKYhC", "username" : "hWvHzBCjs3TuttLMJ", "description" : "sub item 1", "startdate" : ISODate("2018-08-08T00:00:00Z"), "status" : "IN PROGRESS", "parent" : "2ENP9grLxHmCLNYfm" }
```

Comment: Can you please add an example document that is used to be displayed in the template? Otrherwise it is hard to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I've just added example parent and child at the end. Thanks